# How to make ViewController load itself from nib on viewDidLoad() properly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a nib file for my CustomViewController and every time I want to present this Controller I do

```
    let vc = CustomViewController(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What I want is to make CustomViewController to load itself from nib by itself. So that the call in the parent VC would be like this

```
    let vc = CustomViewController()
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CustomViewController add this init method. it will works as per your need.

```
convenience init() {
     self.init(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: nil)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @Theseven7 If you this found answer useful, you can accept it so another users can directly use it.

Answer (score 2):

try this way....

```
MyViewClass *myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewClassNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
```